# Disable checkbox in Telerik Grid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, client-side-templating

Is it possible to DISABLE a Checkbox in the Telerik gridview in MVC pattern? 
I am using clientTemplate and not Server side. 
The requirement is as - A Column containing checkbox needs to be disabled based on the value in another column in the corresponding row. 
Is it possible to implement in Javascript ? Please let me know if I am not clear..

Thanks in advance..

```
columns.Bound(i => i.Visible).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' <#=Visible? checked='checked' : '' #> />").Width("7%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Client Side events when RowDataBound. Do something like this code.

```
    function onRowDataBound(e) {

    if (e.dataItem.ColumnB == "MatchingValue") {
        $(e.row).find('#checkboxId').attr("disabled", true);

    }
```